# call method from DLL in java7

Tags: java, dll

From what I understood dll are not standardized. thus one cannot just call something in a dll.
However I found this :http://johannburkard.de/software/nativecall/

This library allow you to call any method from a dll in java, so it seems that you can call any method in a dll.
but it was done for 32 bit system, thus I cannot use it.

I have this dll, autohotkey.dll, I know there is the method "ahkExec" inside which take a String as parameter.

Is this really not possible to run it from java without using some kind of c++ magic?

Thanks.

ps : here is how it is done with nativeCall : https://gist.github.com/brigand/1526712

Comment: You can not call every dll's method: The method-names must have a specific name. But you can redirect the method-calls using a custom dll.

Answer (score 0):

You've been able to call DLLs in Java since version 1.0 using [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html).

Comment: JNI needs you to place a header, here there is none

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic in invoking external methods but you have to follow some rules based on  what JNI provides .

If you need to use one function from library you could write a specific Wrapper-class like in this [tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

For more tricky things better to work with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to explore random DLL for functions. In your case i suggest you to verify that you have necessary library with expected function. It is easy to do with tool  [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html)